# Coger el id del button seleccionado

Tags: java, botón

Tengo un formulario en el cual necesito saber que botón he pulsado, para sacarle el `id`,y asi con el `id` borrar una fila en una BD, el problema lo tengo en como sacar el `id` del botón. Pongo todo el código que influye:

```
<form class="form-horizontal"  action="Propietario" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="ajax" value="" />
<input type="hidden" name="accion" value="modRatios" />
<table id="ratios" class="display dataTable no-footer">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th><span class="texto" data-i18n="panelcontrol.propietario.precios.horas">...</span></th>
            <th><span class="texto" data-i18n="panelcontrol.propietario.precios.preciomax">...</span></th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <c:forEach items="${sessionScope.propietarioRatios}" var="ratios" varStatus="myIndex">
        <tr>
            <td><input type="text" name="horas${myIndex.index + 1}" value="<c:out value="${ratios.horasRD}" />" style="margin:1em auto;" required></td> 
            <td><input type="text" name="precioMax${myIndex.index + 1}" value="<c:out value="${ratios.descuentoRD}" />" style="margin:1em auto;" required></td>
            <td><button class="btn btnaction btnamarillo" name="accion" value="borrarRatios" id="ratio${ratios.idratio}" type="button"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span></button> </td>//Este es el button en cuestion!!!
        </tr>
        </c:forEach>
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <td><button class="btn btnaction" id="add" type="button"><span class="texto" data-i18n="panelcontrol.propietario.precios.añadir">...</span><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span></button></td>
            <td><button class="btn btnaction btnamarillo" type="submit" id="precioRat"><span class="texto" data-i18n="panelcontrol.propietario.precios.guardar">...</span><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-floppy-disk"></span></button></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>
```

Este es el formulario, el `c:forEach` saca filas en funcion de los datos que haya en la base de datos, que pueden ser 1 o varios, en el button, los ids, son estilo *ratio1*, *ratio2*, *ratio10*...

```
if(vAccion!=null){
            switch(vAccion){
                case "misusos":
                    cargarmisusuos(request, response, base);
                    break;
                case "ocupacion":
                    cargarocupacion(request, response, base);
                    break;
                case "plazas":
                    cargarplazas(request, response, base);
                    break;
                case "plazaactivar":
                    activarplaza(request, response, base);
                    break;
                case"plazasmultiple":
                    activarplazamultiple(request, response, base);
                    break;
                case "facturas":
                    cargarfacturas(request, response, base);
                    break;
                case "generarfacturas":
                    generarfactura(request, response, base);
                    break;
                case "descargarfactura":
                    descargarfactura(request, response, base);
                    respuestapordefecto = false;
                    break;
                case "precios":
                    cargarratios(request, response, base);
                    cargarcomunidades(request, response, base);
                    break;
                case "modCoeficiente":
                    modificarCoeficiente(request, response, base);
                    break;
                case "modRatios":
                    modificarRatios(request, response, base);
                    break;
                case "borrarRatios":
                    borrarRatios(request,response,base);
                    break;
                default:
                    request.setAttribute("errorpanelcontrol", "propietarioaccionnopermitida");
                    break;
            }

        }

private void borrarRatios (HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, BaseWeb base){
       //Establecemos la navegacion activa en la sesión
        HttpSession session = request.getSession();
        PanelControlNav pcnav = (PanelControlNav)session.getAttribute("PanelControlNav");
        pcnav.setNavActivo("propietario");
        pcnav.setTabActivo("propietario", "propprecios");
        session.setAttribute("PanelControlNav", pcnav);

        PropietarioWebControler.borrarRatios(request, response, base);
   }
```

Ese `switch`, depende el botón que pulse manda a un método u otro, pero claro si tengo 10 botones de borrar, irá al mismo método, pero no pasa el `id` ni nada.

```
public static void borrarRatios (HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, BaseWeb base){
        HttpSession session = request.getSession();

        RatioDescuentoControlador ratContr = new RatioDescuentoControlador(base.getVariablesGlobales());

        try{

        }catch(Exception ex){
            base.getLoggerGarageScanner().error("Se ha producido un error");
            request.setAttribute("errorpanelcontrol", "propietariocomunidaderrorcarga");
        }
        finally{

        }
    }
```

Y este es el método donde tengo que borrar las filas de la BD. (eso ya se hacerlo)

Answer (score 0):

Lo más usado en estos casos es un `<input type="hidden" name="nombreAccion" value="ratio${ratios.idratio}">`. Haciendo esto tienes un campo invisible del cual puedes sacar el valor, que es igual al id del botón.

```
  <c:forEach items="${sessionScope.propietarioRatios}" var="ratios" varStatus="myIndex">
            <tr>
                <td><input type="text" name="horas${myIndex.index + 1}" value="<c:out value="${ratios.horasRD}" />" style="margin:1em auto;" required></td> 
                <td><input type="text" name="precioMax${myIndex.index + 1}" value="<c:out value="${ratios.descuentoRD}" />" style="margin:1em auto;" required></td>
                <td><button class="btn btnaction btnamarillo" name="accion" value="borrarRatios" id="ratio${ratios.idratio}" type="button"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span></button> </td>//Este es el button en cuestion!!!
                <td><input type="hidden" name="nombreAccion" value="ratio${ratios.idratio}"></td>
            </tr>
  </c:forEach>
```

Y cogerías el id a borrar de la siguiente manera:

```
String id =  (String)request.getParameter("nombreAccion");
```

Comment: ¿Y cuántos campos `nombreAccion` enviará el formulario al hacer submit?  ]:)

Comment: Lo pruebo, y te comento si me funciona, muchas gracias!

Comment: No me funciona, porque el metodo, me coge un input hidden que tengo ya pueso, el de modRatios

Comment: @urrutias pero les habrás puesto distinto nombre, no?

Comment: no, porque no se cuando botones hay, puede haber 1 o 100, entonces no puedo hacer un switch con opciones infinitas

Answer (score 0):

El valor de ID simplemente no existe para el servidor; el navegador ni siquiera lo envía. Así que asigna el id del ratio al `value` del button, que es un valor que sí se enviará en el request.

```
<button ... name="accion" value="borrarRatio${ratios.idRatio}" id="ratio${ratios.idratio}" type="submit">
```

Luego sólo tienes que modificar tu tratamiento para que, si `accion="borrarRatio" + [número]`, recuperar el número. Por ejemplo, mediante regexp, o simplemente con `substrings` y `startsWith`, etc.

La otrat alternativa es poner un campo oculto y, al pulsar el botón, asignarle el valor correspondiente mediante javascript, pero me parece una complicación innecesaria.

Por supuesto, en todos los casos el problema es que lo que hayas escrito en otros campos de otros ratios se perderá y se voverá a cargar desde la capa de negocio. Considera -cuando tengas bastante más de soltura- echarle una mirada al desarrollo con Ajax.

Comment: le echare un vistazo a lo que me dices,hare un if antes del switch, y si es accion, va al switch, si es el ratios, llamo al metodo directamente. Lo pruebo y te comento

Comment: Le estoy echando un vistazo, y no creo que me pueda servir tal y como me lo propones, porque yo no se el numero de  botones que hay, puede haber 1 o 100, entonces no se como hacerlo la verdad

Comment: Al servidor le llegará un parámetro `accion` con valor `borrarRatio1`, o `borrarRatio2`, o `borrarRatio3`, según el botón que pulses... Si no sabes cómo sacar el número y el identificador de la operación de allí, entonces deberías empezar a repasar la programación en Java desde cero antes de meterte en historias de JSPs y similares.

Comment: Vale nada, pensaba que el borrarratio estaba en el name, mea culpa, sry